# How to design it in a spark- streaming way?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

My current project functionality running in batch mode i.e. runs daily at night.

Where the following steps performed my application

1. Read the data from oracle
2. clean and transform the data
3. Identify the algorithem & attach it
4. Run the attached algorithem
5. Store results in Cassandra.

Currently, I need to write this as a streaming application.
We decided to use Kafka & Spark Structured Streaming tech stack.

How to break/group above functionality to implement it in a streaming way. i.e. spark-jobs.
What should be the medium of communication between those spark-jobs?
What is the industry standard for the above?
If two people want to work on below two steps

2. clean and transform the data
3. Identify the algorithm & attach it

What should be the interface?
Please guide me.

Comment: Does it have to be Spark? I can contribute an answer based on Kafka alone if that would be of interest

Comment: @Robin Moffatt  sure you can ...let me from it i can derive spark one....plz go ahead.